# sqlite - WHERE statements using a multiple of two columns

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, sqlite

I am currently working on a project using sqlite in python 2.7 and need to return rows where the value of column A * column B is greater than a certain number. Here is what the code looks like:

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE validation=1 AND colA * colB > 10000')
```

The only issue is that this doesn't work... I know it's possible in MySQL so I was hoping it would also work in sqlite, although I haven't had any luck finding a means of getting this done.
So my questions is: Is it possible to perform this type of operation with sqlite and if yes, how?

EDIT: Here is more complete code, I honestly had assumed that I had a small syntax error or it simply wasn't possible. Because my code is quite long, I don't feel it's possible to post everything. The table I am trying to query was built as follows:

```
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_1(ticker TEXT, colA INTEGER, colB INTEGER, company_name TEXT, market_cap TEXT, sector TEXT, validation INTEGER, UNIQUE(ticker) ON CONFLICT IGNORE)')
```

The first few entries in the table are as follows:

ticker,colA,colB,company_name,market_cap,sector,validation

"ACFN","0.18","71,200","Acorn Energy","5.16M","Industrial","1"

"ADGE","0.3","64,458","American DG","14.71M","Industrial Goods","1"

"ACUR","0.97","66,358","Acura Pharmaceuticals","11.52M","Healthcare","1"

Also, using the following statement does return the last row from above.

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE validation=1 AND colB > 25000 AND colA> 0.5')
```

But if this statement returns the last column, then my original code which multiplies colA with colB should do the same.

Comment: "The only issue is that this doesn't work" - Why not? Are you getting an error or is the result not correct?

Comment: According to [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html), it looks like `*` should be supported...

Comment: What do you mean by doesn;t work? Does it give error, empty result or something else?

Comment: Ah, sorry. It returns an empty list, although the values are in the table. No errors.

Comment: The code you've shown works perfectly, as demonstrated [here](http://ideone.com/1Kx168). Therefore, the problem is in the code you haven't shown. Please reduce your original program to the shortest possible program that demonstrates the error. Please [edit] your question and copy-paste that short program into your question. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: Ok, so I have found the problem... Because my value in colB has a comma, the table read it as a decimal point. I complete overlooked this as colA has a period as a decimal point and I didn't think both comma and period would be accepted (I imagined it would overlook commas or throw an error). Careless mistake on my part! Thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, just to make it official and close the matter, I will write down the answer to my own question. 
The data entered into colA took on a decimal value (ex: 0.91) and that entered into colB took on an integer value greater than 1000 (ex: 31,000). When I tried to build a SELECT statement such as:

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE validation=1 AND colB > 25000 AND colA> 0.5')
```

it returned the values I wanted because 31,000 > 25000 is True and 0.91 > 0.5 is true. However, when I tried to multiply both columns together in the WHERE statement, it read both numbers as decimal values. Therefore the statement colA * colB > 10000 was false because 0.91*31.000 = 28.21. Simply removing the commas in colB solved the problem.
Nevertheless, this issue is still curious as it only reads the 31,000 as 31.000 when one tries to perform a mathematical operation.